Method to encrypt text that outputs only alphabetic characters
OK so I want to be able to securely encrypt text (ideally AES?) in such a way that the encrypted text output only contains alphabetic characters. Most encoding schemes I've found include numbers which I don't want. I know that this is really an encoding problem because the output is ultimately just bytes. But of course it ultimately has to be reversible.
I've looked into some different encryption algorithms and encoding schemes but none of them have been what I was looking for

You can encode every 2 bytes into 3 base-52 characters, for example.
